# Creating a List of a Range is slow, are there alternatives?

Tags: python, list, performance, range

so I have to create a List of a big range and am trying to accomplish this with `list(range(number1, number2))`and the numbers `number1` and `number2` can have a big difference, for example 235 and 4323246376. Now, this takes a long time to process. Can this process be sped up?

Comment: I think is best you provide more details about your use case

Comment: No, this is the fastest way in Python to create such a list. The only way to make it faster would be to avoid creating this list. What do you need it for?

Comment: @DaniMesejo @mkrieger1 I want to check how many numbers in a range are in another list, and for that I use ```numpy.intersect1d(listWithRange, OtherList)```

Comment: @lorhof1 Then you all need to check the numbers in otherList than are greater or equal to number1 and less or equal to number2. No need to create the list

Comment: @DaniMesejo thanks. what would be the most efficient way to count the items that satisfy conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to use the list as a filter to count items in another list, you should not be using a range at all.

For example:

```
count = numpy.sum(theList >= 235) - numpy.sum(theList >= 4323246376)
```

Answer (score 0):

What use case are you going to achieve with this?

In case you are going to use this list once, don't typecast the range object into a list.
When you typecast the range object into a list, It stores all the numbers in a list which costs you memory.
You can just iterate over the range object.